# I can't open my MySQL Workbench (workbench execution error)

Tags: mysql-workbench, execution

[image]

I'm scared to ask this because people can be a little mean on here but I've watched 1000 of YouTube videos and went through just as many google searches. I was trying to create a data dictionary for mysql diagram. I used this website https://dataedo.com/kb/tools/mysql-workbench/how-to-export-data-dictionary#toc_0 to help me. I downloaded the .py link listed in the install plugin step. The followed the instructions in mysql. It said the plugin install was successful and to restart my workbench. After that I started getting the error shown in the picture. I have tried everything:

1. Restart workbench
2. Repair workbench through msi download
3. Followed the steps in this link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-do-i-kill-all-the-processes-in-mysql-show-processlist
4. Updated all my sql products in mysql installer
5. Made sure mysql services were turned on and running

I don't know what else to do. I can't even open workbench to see if the plugin is the issue because again I can't get in. I just need some help

Answer (score 0):

That is a strannge error, where mysql workbench has some corrupt files.

1. Deinstall MySQL Workbench with the MySQL Installer
2. Install Workbench again

So everything will start normal again, the configuration and connections will stay and can be used again as normal

Comment: I just tried to install and re-install from the mysql installer. The same error still popped up. The only thing that could have been the issue is that when I re-installed they gave me a error saying this path is already taken and do you want to continue, I said yes. Maybe it's still connecting to the old system through the path

Comment: you **first need** to deinstall workbench everything e3lse fails

Comment: Sorry I meant I went my mysql installer removed workbench, the removal was complete then re-installed it back and when the workbench was re-installed the error popped back up immediately.

Comment: then try the uninstall under apps

Answer (score 0):

This is not an installation issue, so don't waste your time by trying to fix this issue by repeating the installation.

The error comes from the approach where MySQL Workbench tries to ensure there's only one instance of it running. For that it searches the process list for another instance and, if one was found, sends the command line parameters it got to that instance, letting the already running instance handle them (and shuts itself down after that).

But again: this happens only if another instance is found, so check your process list carefully. Filter by the term "MySQL" to see any MySQL related processes (including that of a MySQL server). Shutdown/kill any of these processes and try launching WB again.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happened to me and it was like what the heck. Don't waste your time to uninstall and reinstall because it won't solve your problem.

Solution: open your file explorer and delete the entire folder "Workbench"

Path: %appdata%\MySQL\Workbench

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with this file.

Just as Jr Relampagos says, delete the .py file here : AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\modules

Restart Workbench, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

With me I'm just go to C:\Users<USER>\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\modules and then delete the .py file you install, then open the Workbench again